# Using jQuery to Highlight (Select) All Text in a Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text box with some text in it , onclick event I want to run a javascript function to select (highlight) all text that is in this box , how I can do that with jquery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may take a look at [this article](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/PostId/320/Using-jQuery-to-Highlight-Select-All-Text-in-a-Te):

> Let's assume that we have the following text input:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" id="txtInput" />
> ```
>
> In most cases, we would want to have this feature available to all
>   textboxes across our website, so we would create a function to handle
>   this, and call it as needed.  Calling this function with the expected
>   argument will make execute the highlighting of the text.
>
> ```
> function selectAllText(textbox) {
> textbox.focus();
> textbox.select(); }
> ```
>
> Assuming you are developing against DotNetNuke 5, or have jQuery already imported into your website, add the following jQuery to your site for each textbox.  (If you have a lot of textboxes, we could do this differently, but that's for a different post.)
>
> ```
> jQuery('#txtInput').click(function() { selectAllText(jQuery(this)) });
> ```

Answer (score 15):

No need for jQuery, this is simple with the DOM and works in all mainstream browsers:

```
input.onfocus = function() { this.select(); };
```

If you must do it with jQuery, there's very little difference:

```
$(input).focus(function() { this.select(); });
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work in IE 6... but who cares!! Hehehehe

Comment: It will. I'm pretty sure the non-jQuery version will work in IE 3. Certainly IE 4.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
$('input').click(function() {
 // the select() function on the DOM element will do what you want
 this.select();
});
```

Of course, then you can't click on the element to select an arbitrary point in the input, so it might be better to fire that event on `focus` instead of `click`

[Quick Demo w/ click](http://www.jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/) or [w/ focus](http://www.jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/1)

Comment: @Zoidberg - Nope, that would be `narf` --- Although pronounced the same, `gnarf` is simply my last name backwards.

Answer (score 3):

this works best for me.

```
$('myTextbox').select();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't jquery, but for completeness of the answers to this question, you can use this on the text input itself:

```
 onclick="this.select();"
```

For example:

```
<input type="text" value="abc" onclick="this.select();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where I typically do this is in

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTextBox').focus();
    $('#myTextBox').select();
}
```

for the first textbox that I want filled in.
That way if I'm preserving state; and if the user backtracks to the page then it automatically highlights it all for typeover.

Useful technique for things like search boxes...