# Displaying a Large amount of text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to display a list of email addresses on a page that can then be copied and then pasted into an email client. Why they want it done this way is not my concern, I just have to do it.

What I'm wondering is what's the best way to go about displaying this? I'm not sure if I should use a giant label or a textbox or whether there's even something better.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: Not sure if this matters, but the addresses are being pulled from a database so I don't have them ready to simply hard code them into a page. I'm new to ASP.NET stuff and web development in general so please bear with me.

Comment: div with an overflow?

Comment: @Marc B you should post that as an answer!

Comment: If the goal is to get the addresses to an email client, why not generate a mailto: link and forget about the display?

Comment: No idea, I'm just doing what I'm told. There's also an SMTP server set up so technically a user could just write a message and a subject and then shoot it out that way but they want a list of the email addresses.

I think this comes down to "It's what the customer wants" even though the customer is a moron...

Comment: @Jabsy Re: your edit, what I provided was an example of how server-side controls/code might render the HTML for output.  If you need help with how to get your addresses out of the DB, please post the code/markup you already have so we have a starting point to work from and some idea of your database schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this (super simple) markup and it copy/pastes fine into Outlook 2010 and Gmail.

```
<div>
    user@domain.com<br />
    user@domain.com<br />
    user@domain.com<br />
    user@domain.com<br />
    user@domain.com<br />
    user@domain.com<br />
</div>
```

Edit: Is compactness or ease of selection/copying a requirement?  If so then please specify what you would prefer/is required so an appropriate example can be provided.

---

Edit 2: Based on the stated size of your address list, I think this markup pattern would work best as a HTML-only solution.

```
E-mail Address Copy Instructions
    <ol>
        <li>Click inside the box below</li>
        <li>Press Ctrl-A to select all addresses</li>
        <li>Press Ctrl-C to copy all selected text</li>
    </ol>
    <textarea style="height: 150px;">user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
user@domain.com
</textarea>
```

---

Edit 3:

Assuming your have a `List(Of String)`, here is an example.

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150">
```

Code:  (Please excuse if my c# is not perfect, I usually code in VB)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<String> liAddresses = new List<String>();
        //Define list of addresses for demonstration purposes
        //Replace with fetch from DB
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            liAddresses.Add(i.ToString() + "user@domain.com");
        }
        //Load TextBox with list of addresses, will render as <textarea>
        foreach (String strAddress in liAddresses)
        {
            TextBox1.Text += strAddress + "\r\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pulling from a db in list form, and I need to display it on a screen so a user can copy and paste it into another email client. Seeing as the end users are most likely worthless, ease of selection and copying would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm fine with pulling the values from the DB, I've already written the functions that return a list to me full of everything I need. My question I guess would be how to go about from getting the individual strings to output in the format you have

Answer (score 2):

Textarea?  Could additionally have some javascript to select all the text on a click into the box.

Comment: I like the idea of selection Javascript, can you provide an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005227/using-jquery-to-highlight-select-all-text-in-a-textbox

As mentioned in some of the other answers, this is probably not the most ideal method, but if the client is looking for an easy copy+paste, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Part of coding responsibly is directing your users away from shotting themselves in the foot.

Having said that I would probably output the data with a literal, string builder and separate entries with `<br />`, and as Marc suggests wrap all that in a div with overflow and height set.

Comment: I agree, but `overflow:scroll;` could cause useability issues for some users when they try to select the contents.  They would need to use the drag-scroll mechanism which is beyond the abilities of many basic users.

Answer (score 0):

How long is the list? Depending on the size of the list of email addresses, there are various things you could do - ie. implement a scrollable listview for most sizes, a paged gridview for a very large list, or a single textbox if your list is very small.

Comment: It's a rather large list. Essentially it's a list of everyone who has access to the site, so upwards of 500

Answer (score 0):

I would put it this on a [Textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) element. That way can be copied easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like a ListBox, so you can iterate through them without needing to parse the list with a delimeter. The other alternative is to do it Outlook style, and display the addresses in a textbox with a semicolon as a delimeter.

One benefit to the semicolon delimited format is that the MailMessage class accepts a list of recipients separated by a semicolon, so it would make the process of sending the email a littl easier.

Answer (score -1):

i would use a scrollable list view!
give a look here for the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.scrollable.aspx